How to extract the last item from a table name in SQL using regex in PHP?
Question:
I have an SQL query in the format of:
SELECT dt FROM a.b.c WHERE dt = '20210808' LIMIT 10;

The table name in this SQL statement is a.b.c, and I want to extract only the last part of the table name (c). The table name always follows this pattern: schema1.schema2.table_name. My goal is to extract the table_name (the last item) using a regular expression in PHP.
Here’s my current attempt:
$sql = "SELECT dt FROM a.b.c WHERE dt = '20210808' LIMIT 10";
$tmp_table_name_pattern = '/\.([^.]*$)/';
preg_match_all($tmp_table_name_pattern, $sql, $match);
print_r($match);

However, the result I get is:
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => .c WHERE dt = '20210808' LIMIT 10
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => c WHERE dt = '20210808' LIMIT 10
    )
)

What I expect is to extract only c as the table name. How can I modify my regular expression or PHP code to achieve this?
What I've tried:

I understand that the regex pattern /\.([^.]*$)/ is matching everything after the last dot, but it also includes extra content after the table name (like WHERE, etc.).
I need a way to precisely stop at the table name and avoid matching extra parts of the query.

Expected result:
I want the output to be:
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => c
    )
)


Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is very broad, and it might be beneficial if you split it up in a few more targetted questions. Currently, any answer that could potentially come to your aid might actually not be helpful at all. Please take the time to revise your question(s).

does the regular expression is different between various environments like SHELL、 PHP、JAVA, etc?
Yes, they do differ. Term flavour is used to denote particular version. Examples are

POSIX Basic Regular Expression (BRE)
POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE)
Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)

If you are interested in flavour used in particular programming language please refer to Regular Expression Engine Comparison Chart
